# Render a component onPress(TouchableOpacity/Button) in React Native

Tags: react-native, api, react-functional-component, touchableopacity, onpress

I have a functional that has a fetch call to Wordnik Api and it returns one random word. It works all fine, but am trying to set up a TouchbaleOpacity/Button that will render that component onPress so I can get a random word every time the user clicks on the button. I have the other component in a separate file, how do call it on button Press?

```
`export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const onPress = () => {
    //return component
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <Button title="Next word" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Wordnik />
    </View>
  );
}`
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a props `key` on your component and change that key every time on your button's `onPress` so component will render every time when key change as following :

```js
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [tempKey, setTempKey] = useState(0);
  const onPress = () => {
    //return component
    setTempKey(tempKey+1);
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
        <Button title="Next word" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Wordnik key={tempKey.toString()} />
    </View>
  );
}
```