# How to call a component onPress TouchableOpacity in react-native

Tags: react-native, components, touchableopacity, onpress

I am using TouchableOpacity from react-native. The code is:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    <Text style={styles.supplementItem}>{item.item}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

where the OnPress function is as:

```
 const onPress = () => (
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-sequences
  <Text style={styles.supplementItem}>Hello</Text>
  this.setState({tempKey: tempKey + 1})
);
```

I looked at: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66038779/render-a-component-onpresstouchableopacity-button-in-react-native) and tried to do like it. But this is not working. I am setting my states as follows:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  tempKey: 0,
};

}
```

Kindly help me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The question which you mentioned is using function based components and you are using class based components as you showed the costructor part which proves that.

So `onPress` must be a method in that class in your case, so you don't need the `const` keyword before it and you need to call it in this way ; `this.onPress`

In nutshell, your whole component should be like this;

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';

class YourComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tempKey: 0,
      show: false
    };
    
    }
    onPress = () => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-sequences
      this.setState(prevState => ({tempKey: prevState.tempKey + 1}))
    };

render() {
   return (
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 100, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}} onPress={() => this.onPress()}>
        <Text>Hello (item.item in your case)</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

      <Text key={this.state.tempKey.toString()}>Hello {this.state.tempKey}</Text>
</View>
  )


}


}
export default YourComp;
```

If you want to show some component conditionally;

```
this.state = {
      ...,
     show: false

}
```

Then in the `onPress` method;

```
this.setState(prevState => ({show: !prevState.show})) // this will make <Text /> to toggle the modal when clicked.
```

Then in the render method;

```
<Text>
  {this.state.show && (
    <YourNewComponent />

) || null}


</Text>
```

Comment: I tried this solution. But i am not getting anything

Comment: What is item here and why you want to show a Text component on press

Comment: Edited my answer. Check that if that is what you want. If not then please comment what is missing. Also comment if you need explanation

Comment: This didn't work either. Actually I want to call a modal component on pressing this <Text /> component. But I want the modal component to be in a separate file

Comment: You can make another state variable and set that to true when you click <Text /> and on that basis make the modal visible....